# Oracle Database change notification

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am new to DCN, can I use it to detect updates on a column in my table along with inserts in that table ?
I am referring to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28815)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can - Change Notifications made for that. You need to register СN listener with query to watch (it can a whole table `select * from your_table` or part of it `select column1 from your_table where column2='xxx'`) and callback function . You should understand that it is async mechanism changes will not detect immediately, but after some time.
Your documentation's link shows way how to implement it using JDBC.
Read [it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_chngnt.htm#CIHFDFDJ) if you want to use Oracle PL/SQL for that.

Comment: Thanks! What is the delay for the changes to be notified ?
Also for above modified select statement 'DCN_QUERY_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION' should be true right ?

Comment: Also can you comment which is better approach w.r.t. performance using just query or with pl-sql ? The table serves data with updates 5k a minute at max.

Comment: On my practise it was 1-2 second. As I understood for JDBC it should be true. But not sure. I have used PL SQL for that.
What do you mean by telling performance using just query or with pl-sql? What is a query?
P.S. You can also use normal Oracle triggers to detect DML operations.

Comment: `Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
 at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:540)
 at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:139)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.NTFConnection.unmarshalOneNSPacket(NTFConnection.java:334)
 at oracle.jdbc.driver.NTFConnection.run(NTFConnection.java:182) `

Comment: I am getting this exception very often so i thought Its an issues with the method i am using, any resolve on this ?

Comment: Please describe first what are you needs of using Change Notifications?

Comment: my one of the table holds data for business transactions and i have run a job when there's no transaction for 5 minutes, I am trying to achieve this using `Timer()` in java.
So to get notified if any transaction is executed I need some triggering ( I do not have code access as it is 3rd party tool ) for that purpose I am using database change notification.

Comment: Sagar, I think the 
1)best way to found the reason of the issue is to contact Oracle DBA. He can trace session of your job and provide you full information about query executing and found where data holds. 
2) If it is not possible try to use only Oracle tools - you are learning 2 new technologies in a moment (DCN in JDBC and DCN itself)
3) if it is also not possible use this example http://appcrawler.com/wordpress/2012/08/28/jdbc-and-oracle-database-change-notification/
It is fully workable. I have tested it on 50 000 transactions with 3 DML operations. No issues, all rowid was provided.

Comment: But you should understand that CN create only after fixing of transaction (commit) - if for example deadlock lock your action in your table you will not see any notification. Also you will get ROWIDs, not exact data - to get exact data please use triggers - you will see what data was before and after DML opertion.